# Can I setup a backup migrate schedule from settings.php

Tags: 7, backups, configuration, migrations

I am using [Pantheon](http://getpantheon.com) to host a development, staging and production drupal 7 site.  I have backup migrate module setup to perform period backups. When I migrate the production site's content to the staging site for testing of new features, the backup migrate settings come with, and all of sudden I now have both production and staging servers backing up to a remote server.  I don't mind having to delete the schedules every time I perform the migration, however I'd hate to write this step into the SOP for other developers as they come on the project.  So is there a way to setup a backup migrate schedule in settings php?  My only thought is to add some config variables in settings.php, and then create a custom module that builds a backup migrate schedule based on these config variables.  I feel like there could be a more elegant solution than this.  Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://help.getpantheon.com/pantheon/topics/is_it_possible_to_use_the_environment_indicator_module_on_pantheon) (the first part is about the Environment Indicator module but the last part is about Backup and Migrate), Pantheon forbids the use of the Backup and Migrate module on their platform.  While it is possible to make Backup and Migrate settings [exportable](http://drupal.org/node/373786), including for use in settings.php, it's probably best not to violate your web host's policies.

That said, Pantheon should really start writing their rules down clearly somewhere.